Move contact on iPhone from one list to another
My one and only Contact List is for a Microsoft Exchange server interface.  That's the interface to an AkrutoSync app on my Windows laptop, which in turn syncs with the Outlook desktop app on the laptop.  As far as this question is concerned, the important detail is that for all intents and purposes, the iPhone maintains a Contacts list that syncs with an Exchange Server.  In the image below, it shows as "All AkrutoSync Exchange".
I recently migrated from a dying iPhone SE 1st generation to 3rd generation.  Apple phone support helped me migrate all my information and apps.  I have since discovered that my new iPhone has an "All iPhone" list, also shown below.  It is too painful to locate the discrepencies between the two lists, so I'm going to try an kill the "All iPhone" list.
However, there is a new contact that a friend entered into my phone yesterday which doesn't show up in either of the two lists above.  It is in the "All iCloud" list, also shown below.  I Googled how to move the contact to the "All AkrutoSync Exchange" list, but it requires using Mac, iTunes, and/or iCloud.  At iCloud.com, I only see the "All iCloud" list, so I can't drag the contact to "All AkrutoSync Exchange" in the cloud.
As for iTunes, it's way too big for such a tactical function.  I would be managing a mammoth platform in order to use 0.00001% of the functionality.  It would be infinitely quicker to transcribe the contact by hand.
Is there no way to move/copy contacts between lists on the iPhone itself?
I tried emailing and importing the contact.  I was able to "Share" the contact by emailing my Gmail account.  I'm getting stuck at the stage of importing.  When I descend into the destination list "All AkrutoSync Exchange", I can see no "Import" function.  Creating a blank contact also reveals no import function.

I have iOS updating automatically.  It is now at version 18.1.1.

If you open this particular contact and scroll to end there is "Add to list". You can add it to wanted list and remove unwanted.

at my last job there were a lot of iphones and a lot of issues with exchange. Youmight be better served with the free Outlook for ios than tha mail app

@Aivar Paalberg: After the Notes field, I see Send Message, Share Contact, Add to Favourites, Add to Emergency Contacts, and Share My Location.  I don't see Add to list.  Are you on an iPhone with iOS 18.1.1?

@Steve Chambers: I've used AkrutoSync for years.  This is a one-off problem, probably resulting from migrating iPhones.  If I can't solve it, I'll just manually transcribe the contact.  Thanks.

I have iOS 18.1.1 and I have Add to List between Add to Favourites and Add to Emergency Contacts

The options available may depend on the list that the contact resides in.  Or maybe how the contact was created.  Checking other contacts in other lists, I see no option other than Share My Location.  :(
